Dialog controls are no longer visible when I scroll back up the screen
I am trying to cater for smaller displays as I know that some users have these devices. And the layout of my dialog is such that some of the content is not visible for them.
Unfortunately, it is not practical for me to supply a copy of my exact dialog resources. Suffice to say that I have dragged a vertical scroll bar on to the dialog and mapped it to a variable.
I have added the following code:
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    int nDelta;
    int nMaxPos = 100; // Maximum scroll position, adjust as needed

    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_LINEUP:
        nDelta = -10; // Scroll up by 10 units
        break;
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        nDelta = 10; // Scroll down by 10 units
        break;
    case SB_PAGEUP:
        nDelta = -50; // Scroll up by a page (adjust as needed)
        break;
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
        nDelta = 50; // Scroll down by a page (adjust as needed)
        break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        nDelta = nPos - m_nScrollPos;
        break;
    default:
        nDelta = 0;
    }

    // Calculate the new scroll position
    int nNewPos = m_nScrollPos + nDelta;
    nNewPos = max(0, min(nNewPos, nMaxPos));

    // If the position has changed, scroll the window
    if (nNewPos != m_nScrollPos)
    {
        ScrollPartialArea(0, m_nScrollPos - nNewPos);

        m_nScrollPos = nNewPos;
        SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, m_nScrollPos, TRUE);
    }

    __super::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}


// Function to scroll a part of the dialog
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::ScrollPartialArea(int dx, int dy)
{
    // Define the scroll rectangle (portion of the client area to scroll)
    CRect rctScroll;
    CRect rctStatus;
    m_verticalScroll.GetWindowRect(rctScroll);
    m_StatusBar.GetWindowRect(rctStatus);
    ScreenToClient(rctScroll);
    ScreenToClient(rctStatus);
    const CRect scrollRect(0, 0,
        rctScroll.left - 2, rctStatus.top - 2);

    // Define the clipping rectangle (NULL means no clipping)
    CRect* prcClip = nullptr;

    // Region and rectangle for update region
    CRgn updateRgn;
    updateRgn.CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    CRect rcUpdate;

    // Flags for scrolling
    const UINT flags = SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE;

    // Perform the scrolling
    const int result = ScrollWindowEx(
        dx,
        dy,
        &scrollRect,
        prcClip,
        &updateRgn,
        &rcUpdate,
        flags
    );

    // Check the result (0 if an error occurred, otherwise positive value)
    if (result == 0)
    {
        // Handle error (optional)
    }

    // Clean up
    updateRgn.DeleteObject();
}

When I run the program, I find that I can scroll down fine:

Before:



After:


But, when I then scroll back to the top:

I have now lost all the original controls.
How do I address that?

I tried to use DeferWindowPos like this:
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::ScrollPartialArea(int dx, int dy)
{
    // Define the scroll rectangle (portion of the client area to scroll)
    CRect rctScroll;
    CRect rctStatus;
    m_verticalScroll.GetWindowRect(rctScroll);
    m_StatusBar.GetWindowRect(rctStatus);
    ScreenToClient(rctScroll);
    ScreenToClient(rctStatus);
    const CRect scrollRect(0, 0,
        rctScroll.left - 2, rctStatus.top - 2);

    // Assume you want to scroll the controls by (dx, dy) pixels.
    CWnd* pWnd = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); // Get the first child control
    if (!pWnd)
        return;

    // Determine the number of child windows
    int count = 0;
    while (pWnd)
    {
        CRect rctControl;
        pWnd->GetWindowRect(rctControl);
        ScreenToClient(rctControl);
        if (scrollRect.PtInRect(rctControl.CenterPoint()))
        {
            count++;
        }
        pWnd = pWnd->GetNextWindow();
    }

    // Begin the defer window position operation
    HDWP hDWP = BeginDeferWindowPos(count);
    if (!hDWP)
        return;

    pWnd = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); // Reset to the first child control
    while (pWnd)
    {
        CRect rect;
        pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
        ScreenToClient(&rect);
        if (scrollRect.PtInRect(rect.CenterPoint()))
        {
            // Adjust the position by the scroll offset (dx, dy)
            rect.OffsetRect(dx, dy);

            // Add this control to the batch of window position changes
                hDWP = DeferWindowPos(hDWP, pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), nullptr, rect.left, rect.top,
                    rect.Width(), rect.Height(), SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }

        // Move to the next child control
        pWnd = pWnd->GetNextWindow();
    }

    // Apply all the changes
    EndDeferWindowPos(hDWP);
}

But this is what it looks like when I scroll back up:

My logic is flawed.
Infact, if I scroll down just past the left / right arrows and scroll back up step by step:


This article:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/32925/scrollable-dialog-in-pure-win32-api
Works well. It uses ScrollWindow. No issues really, apart from little bit of ghosting. Subject for another question.

Does the dialog have the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style? Are the controls direct children of the dialog?

Note in particular, that controls inside a static control should be siblings of that static control (not children). It looks like you made them children of the static control.

@IInspectable Clip Children is set to false. All the controls on the left hand side are part of my dialog resource template. None of them are dynamically created.

@IInspectable How do you make consoles in a static control as siblings? I have not done anything specifically, apart from set the tab order.

@IInspectable I can confirm that any control that goes off the top of the screen ends up not drawing when scrolling back down. Although I can verify the existence of the controls and they have content. The reason teh group stays is because it never fully goes out of scope.

Would taking advantage of a CFormView (over a CDialog) since you have an MDI-like toolbar?  Not sure about your specific GUI design, but is this a modal dialog on top of the app, or is this literally the "main window".  If it is the main window, consider CFormView.

@franji1 Thanks. It is not possible to do that I am afraid. I have decided to change my approach to  how I scroll my window. Thanks.
